# C# Oracle connection string for DataGrid

Tags: c#, oracle, database-connection

When I import Dataset to application in connnection string I choose "No exclude information from connection string. I will set this information in my aplication".

Now when I compile the form there is nothing to see in the DataGrid, where I must place connection in my application to connet ?

Now I have:

```
 public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection("Data Source=localhost;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=martynas;Password=xxxxxxx;Unicode=True"))
            {
                try
                {
                    con.Open();
                    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
```

This conection is open, but DataGridView still does not show any records. I think that maybe I place connection in wrong method ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not connecting your OracleCommand to anything.  You create it but when it goes out of scope, it ceases to exists.

Comment: Ok, but how to set that my DataGridView using my this connection is possible?

Comment: It's not practical to give you a complete tutorial here.  You need to look at some code samples and perhaps on-line videos to get a grasp of what to do.